# Can we create a pair (a,b) as values in Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, linked-list, hashtable

I'm kind of freshmen in Java. I learned hashtable might help me solve a problem.

I want to create a Hashtable such that every entry of it is a key-value pair of

```
<Float, (a,b) >
```

And every entry contains a linkedlist of many pairs, how can I write codes to implement that?

Comment: So storing a tuple with chained hashing? Are you allowed to use standard Java libraries?

Comment: Is tuple a data structure in Java libraries?

Comment: No, create an class like `Pair` or use `Point` or similar existing class (which one depends on what you need).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `Point` to represent a pair of points, or alternatively your own class with 2 int or double entries. The advantageTof using your own class to wrap and hold the two values together is that it can be as simple and specific to your needs. In any case, those would be your values in the HashTable.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't thought about that

Answer (score 1):

First, create a `Pair` class:

```
//A and B are generics
class Pair<A, B> {
    private A element1;
    private B element2;
    public Pair(A element1, B element2) {
        this.element1 = element1;
        this.element2 = element2;
    }
    //public getters...
}
```

Second, have a `Map<Float, List<Pair<A, B>>>` to insert your key/value:

```
Map<Float, List<Pair<A, B>>> table = new HashMap<Float, List<Pair<A, B>>>();
```

Third, create a `List<Pair<A, B>>` backed by `LinkedList<Pair<A, B>>`:

```
List<Pair<A, B>> myList = new LinkedList<Pair<A, B>>();
```

Fourth, add your list into your map.

```
table.put(1, myList);
```

You should not use `LinkedList` nor `HashMap` classes directly, instead try to [code oriented to interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface). Also, I would recommend you to use another key instead `Float` or `Double` since their values may differ due to [floating point comparison](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/). I would recommend `Integer`, `Long`, `String` or `BigDecimal` instead of `Float`.

Answer (score 0):

the value entry of HashMap can be any Object and a LinkedList is a object so

```
HashMap<typeofkey,LinkedListy<Typeofvalueobject> map = new HashMap<>();
```

just replace the typeofkey and typeofvalue with approbiate types

Answer (score 0):

The object will be as below :

```
HashTable<Object,LinkedList<Object>> obj = new HashTable<Object,LinkedList<Object>>();
```

And to add the element just use `put` method.

Comment: You should avoid usage of `Hashtable` class. Instead, use `Map` backed by `HashMap`.

Comment: Offcource @LuiggiMendoza but OP want HashTable.

Comment: That doesn't mean you *should* answer with `Hashtable` (note that there's no `HashTable` class, check the T). It's similar to show people how to use a `Vector` when you should use `List` backed by `ArrayList`. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1386275/1065197